# SharePoint 2010 external list will not export to Outlook

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, outlook, exchange-server

I have created an external content type in SharePoint 2010 that populates a list from SQL. The list is successfully populated and I can view it through SharePoint. However, if I select the option to "Connect to Outlook" I receive an Error: Access Denied. My account is a farm admin and has full control. The only message I get in the error log is as follows:

> Publish Process failed to publish solution for the List Autotask
>   Clients.
>   0x80070005Access
>   denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authectication was set to kerberos, once I switched it to NTLM it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You seems connected as "System Account" in your browser, but are you also connected as the same user in your Windows session?
Outlook don't use the account use in IE but the one you used to logged in into Windows.